# Using BASH, how can I expand PDSH list of IP addresses?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, ipv4

I have a list of 3000 or so IP addresses that were the result of a pdsh output piped through `dshback -c` which formats the output into a readable format. I like the readability of `dshback -c`, but the problem I have is that IP's with common octets are collapsed to save space. I need to have the full IP address for the rest of my project.

Is there an easy way to convert this input:

```
192.168.38.[217,222],192.168.40.215,192.168.41.[219-222]
```

to this output:

```
192.168.38.217,192.168.38.222,192.168.40.215,192.168.41.219,192.168.41.220,192.168.41.221,192.168.41.222
```

I was thinking sed could be used directly, but I'm not sure how to store the common octets in a variable. For this reason, I believe a bash script will need to be used along with sed. Any help or points in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change an input you can use following form:

```
echo 192.168.38.{217,222} 192.168.40.215 192.168.41.{219..222} | tr ' ' ','
```

Otherwise you can change it by command and eval:

```
eval echo $( echo '192.168.38.[217,222],192.168.40.215,192.168.41.[219-222]' | \
 sed 's/,/ /g;s/\[/{/g;s/]/}/g;s/-/../g;s/\({[0-9]\+\) \([0-9]\+}\)/\1,\2/g' | \
 grep -v '[^0-9{}., ]' ) | tr ' ' ','
```

note, that eval is pretty dangerous on invalidated data, therefore I use `grep '[^0-9{}., ]'` to exclude any unexpected symbols.
`sed` in this command just transforms your original string to a form I've mentioned above.

Comment: Both of these work perfectly. Thanks. I think I understand the sed and grep parts, but I'm not sure on the tr command. Can you explain why it expands bases on curly braces and 2 periods? It looks to me like it is going to replace a space with a comma. I still don't understand after reading the man page.

Comment: We need `tr` here as after `echo` or `eval echo` all ip addresses are space separated and you need the comma separated list. so `tr` just replaces space to comma. regarding brace expansion it's standard bash feature. You can read about it over there : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to use awk then you can try this

```
echo "192.168.38.[217,222],192.168.40.215,192.168.41.[219-222]" |sed 's/\[//g' | sed 's/\]//g' | awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){n=split($i,a,".");IPL="";if(n>1){PIP=a[1] "." a[2] "." a[3];}else{IPL=PIP "." $i;}if(index(a[4],"-") > 0){x=0;split(a[4],b,"-");for(j=b[1];j<=b[2];j++){if(x==0){IPL=PIP "." j;x++;}else{IPL=IPL "," PIP "." j;}}}else if(index(a[4],",") > 0){split(a[4],b,",");IPL=PIP "." b[1] "," PIP "." b[2];}else{if(length(IPL)<=3){IPL=PIP "." a[4];}}printf("%s,",IPL);}}'
```

If you are interested in using this i can explain the logic...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to process it purely with Bash as required. No awks, sed and other stuffs.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
IFS=,

while read -r LINE; do
    OUTPUT=()
    while [[ -n $LINE ]]; do
        case "$LINE" in
        +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]))
            OUTPUT[${#OUTPUT[@]}]=$LINE
            break
            ;;
        +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]),*)
            OUTPUT[${#OUTPUT[@]}]=${LINE%%,*}
            LINE=${LINE#*,}
            ;;
        +([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).\[+([[:digit:],-])\]*)
            SET=${LINE%%\]*}
            PREFIX=${SET%%\[*}
            read -a RANGES <<< "${SET:${#PREFIX} + 1}"
            for R in "${RANGES[@]}"; do
                case "$R" in
                +([[:digit:]]))
                    OUTPUT[${#OUTPUT[@]}]=${PREFIX}${R}
                    ;;
                +([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]]))
                    X=${R%%-*} Y=${R##*-}
                    if [[ X -le Y ]]; then
                        for (( I = X; I <= Y; ++I )); do
                            OUTPUT[${#OUTPUT[@]}]=${PREFIX}${I}
                        done
                    else
                        for (( I = X; I >= Y; --I )); do
                            OUTPUT[${#OUTPUT[@]}]=${PREFIX}${I}
                        done
                    fi
                    ;;
                esac
            done
            LINE=${LINE:${#SET} + 2}
            ;;
        *)
            # echo "Invalid token: $LINE" >&2
            break
        esac
    done
    echo "${OUTPUT[*]}"
done
```

For an input of

```
192.168.38.[217,222],192.168.40.215,192.168.41.[219-222]
```

Running bash temp.sh < temp.txt yields

```
192.168.38.217,192.168.38.222,192.168.40.215,192.168.41.219,192.168.41.220,192.168.41.221,192.168.41.222
```

It's consistent also with ranges. If X is later than Y e.g. 200-100 then it would generate IPS with subsets of 200 to 100. The script could also process multi-line inputs.

And it should also work with mixed ranges like [100,200-250].

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
    $0 = gensub(/(\[[[:digit:]]+),([[:digit:]]+\])/,"\\1+\\2","g")
    gsub(/[][]/,"")

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,a,/\./)
        base  = a[1] "." a[2] "." a[3]
        range = a[4]
        split(range,r,/[+-]/)

        printf (i>1 ? "," : "")
        if (range ~ /+/) {
            printf "%s.%s", base, r[1]
            printf "%s.%s", base, r[2]
        }
        else if (range ~ /-/) {
            for (j=r[1]; j<=r[2]; j++) {
                printf "%s.%s", base, j
            }
        }
        else {
            printf "%s.%s", base, range
        }
    }
    print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
192.168.38.217192.168.38.222,192.168.40.215,192.168.41.219192.168.41.220192.168.41.221192.168.41.222
```

We need the gensub() to change the comma inside the square brackets to a different character (`+`) so we can use the comma outside of the brackets as the field separator and gensub() makes it gawk-specific.